# jquery identifying elements in a row

Tags: jquery

I am a lil new to JQ. I have a table and each row has a unique id like so `<tr id="123">`.

I have a edit button in one of the fields on that row, and I want to turn that row into a form.

How can I grab all the values of each field in that row?

Here is what the table looks like now.

```
<tr id="e2c420d928d4bf8ce0ff2ec19b371514">
   <td><div id="item_name">asdf (asdf)</div></td>

   <td><div id="edit">Edit</div></td>

   <td><div id="item_description">asdf</div></td>

   <td><div id="item_price">1234</div></td>

   <td><div id="item_qty">1</div></td>

   <td><div id="item_total">1234</div></td>
</tr>

<tr id="b2x4123928d4bf8ce0ff2ec19b372138">
   <td><div id="item_name">asdf (asdf)</div></td>

   <td><div id="edit">Edit</div></td>

   <td><div id="item_description">asdf</div></td>

   <td><div id="item_price">1234</div></td>

   <td><div id="item_qty">1</div></td>

   <td><div id="item_total">1234</div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what do you mean by grab the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using classes and `data-id` attributes, but it is up to you.

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr data-id="e2c420d928d4bf8ce0ff2ec19b371514">

        <td><div class="item_name">asdf (asdf)</div></td>

        <td><div class="edit">Edit</div></td>

        <td><div class="item_description">asdf</div></td>

        <td><div class="item_price">1234</div></td>

        <td><div class="item_qty">1</div></td>

        <td><div class="item_total">1234</div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr data-id="b2x4123928d4bf8ce0ff2ec19b372138">
        <td><div class="item_name">asdf (asdf)</div></td>

        <td><div class="edit">Edit</div></td>

        <td><div class="item_description">asdf</div></td>

        <td><div class="item_price">1234</div></td>

        <td><div class="item_qty">1</div></td>

        <td><div class="item_total">1234</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What you need is (assuming you are using jquery 1.4.2+)

```
$('#myTable').delegate('.edit', 'click', function () {
    var trElem = $(this).closest('tr');
    name = trElem.find('div.item_name').text();
    // etc...
});
```

Read up more on `.delegate` and `.closest`. They are less used but awesome methods.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Shrikant! I sort of did those modifications last night, except I used .live vs .delegate. I will be sure to read up on data-id's, .delegate and .closest! 

Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear from your question exactly what you're trying to do, but this will load all the values into an object:

```
var values = {};
$("#e2c420d928d4bf8ce0ff2ec19b371514 div").each(function() {
    var div = $(this);
    values[div.attr("id")] = div.html();
}
```

and you'll be able to reference the values like this:

```
var itemName = values["item_name"];
```

In light of the changes to the question this is what you need to do:

```
$("div#edit").click(function() {
    $("div", this).each(function() {
        var div = $(this);
        if(div.attr("id") !== "edit") {
            var input = $('<input type="text" />').attr("name", div.attr("id")).val(div.html());
            div.replaceWith(input);
        }        
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to change the ids of the divs to classes (and replace `div.attr("id")` with `div.attr("class")` and `$("div#edit")` with `$("div.edit")`, because you should only have one instance of an id per page. You'll also probably want to check the id of each div you process (using a `switch` block) and create a different type of input in each case (depending on your needs).

Comment: Thanks Bennor, I am going to try that out!

Comment: I think that is a step in the right direction, but it's not exactly doing what I am looking for. Let me try and clear up my question.

I have a table with more than one unique row. Each row has a unique id on each <tr>. There is also a edit button on each row. 

My goal is to have this edit button grab all the text values in each field for that specific row, then store them as var's, then replace the entire row with form inputs that contain the vars on each field in that row.

I have updated the table example above. Thanks again!